# HTML/javascript: prevent paint before code executes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a page with a javascript file at the end. the file is placed at the end so that I get access to all the dom elements.
let us say the markup looks like this

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
//lot of markup here
<script src="my-js.js"></script>
<body>
```

the sample markup is just to show the location of my js file.

the first like in the js file (my-js.js) is

```
document.body.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

After the code runs I set the visibility back to hidden

From what I have understood(from a lot of articles related to this including in stackoverflow ones) is that the browser reaches the js, then executes it, and then continues with render and then paints.
If that was true, my code as described should work fine.

However, what is happening now is that, the page is shown  (for less than 500ms) as it is before the code executed, then quickly hidden and then shown again after the code executed.

in short, what I want is:
page is hidden > code executes > page is shown
instead what I get is
page is shown > page is hidden > code executes > page is shown

My question is why is the page shown for that split second? what am I doing wrong here?

PS: Please note that I cannot change the location of the js nor add another. So, do not post any solution that suggest the same. 
More importantly, I want to know why my code is wrong.

Comment: The browser renders tags immediately, before it gets to your `<script>`.

Comment: Can you put a style inline in your top-level element(s) to hide them?

Comment: no, I cannot put anything else in the page. this is like a plugin that the client will add (the script tag) in the page. I have no control over the original page in which it is used.

Comment: I'd move any plugin that messes with the visibility of my page content to /dev/null in a jiffy ... That's just very bad UX; that users prefer to see at least some content instead of waiting in front of an empty screen, is nearly universal consensus I think.

Comment: @CBroe whatever the UX best practices are, end of the day, it all depends what client wants.

Comment: @maX - Have you tried using `defer`? When used correctly this will solve your problem. Please see my answer below.

Comment: _"the file is placed at the end so that I get access to all the dom elements"_ - and you really thought browsers would build the DOM for your convenience first, but hold back starting to render anything, because there _might_ be a script waiting at the very end ...? Ridiculous, it would slow down the current web no end, and any "above the fold" optimization would be pointless to begin with. [...]

Comment: Browsers render parts as of a page as soon as they are comfortable they have enough info to do so, and that is a good thing. Ten years ago people where asking the opposite of what you want, when it came to long render times for their huge tables ...

Comment: @snack_overflow yes, I did. after the answer you posted. still the same. script tag looks like this <script src='my-js.js' defer></script>

Comment: That's what CSS is for, so add `body { visibility: hidden; }` to your style sheet, and then reverse that with your script

Comment: _"whatever the UX best practices are, end of the day, it all depends what client wants"_ - if you mention that upfront, it can be taken into account accordingly. But if you talk about clients and their "pages you have no control over", it sounds like you were looking for a solution to apply on a broad basis, on every site that was interested in your plugin. Browser reality is oriented on what benefits the majority, not some client's obscure wishes. [...]

Comment: Maybe it could make sense in their specific situation to show "nothing" until everything is ready - but to facilitate that, you'd have to work with them a little closer than on a "plugin drop-in" basis, that might require changes to how their site is built on lower levels to begin with.

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to have an inline script do nothing more than set the body visibility to hidden at the very top, to be later reversed by your "main" script - if they can embed your plugin script at the very bottom and want this effect, that should be possible as well.

Comment: Is knowing why more important than how to fix? ... If i got it right, you can't change the code at all? ... if so, then how can you decide the script loads at the end of the body, and if you can decide, why can you not make a change at the beginning the page? ....

Comment: ... can you tell what you _can_ do instead of telling what you _can't_

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using the `defer` method.

> defer means “wait for the parser to finish to execute this”. It’s roughly equivalent to binding your script to the DOMContentLoaded event, or using jQuery.ready. When the code does run, everything in the DOM will be available for you to use. Unlike async, defer’d code will run in the order it appears in the HTML of the page, it is just deferred until after the HTML is fully parsed.

For example:
`<script src="my-js.js" defer></script>`

See more [here](https://eager.io/blog/everything-I-know-about-the-script-tag/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Good! Let's hope the downvoter retracts the downvote.

Comment: @maX - Weird. Try adding `defer` before the `src` and empty your cache. This has worked for me before. `defer` and `async` are really useful.

Comment: Cool suggestion! +1

Comment: First off, `defer` doesn't work properly cross browser, second, in your quote it says _"deferred until **after** the HTML is fully parsed"_. The keyword here is **after**, which is exactly what OP does **not** want, hence the page flashes before it gets hidden.

Comment: @NickyTheWrench How is that cool? ... read my previous comment and you'll see it is the opposite.

Comment: @LGSon I totally forgot about `defer` in the script tag so this was a nice reminder for me. Anyways, I know what the docs say, but I just tested this and the page doesn't flash.

Comment: Code in deferred sometimes runs before FP sometimes after.

Answer (score -2):

Put the `script` tag right at the start of the `body` so it will be evaluated almost exactly as the `body` is rendered.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
document.body.style.visibility = 'hidden';
</script>
<p>Sample text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also add a `style` tag to set the body's visibility to hidden.

```css
body{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <p>Sample text</p>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: @maX In that case, I don't think there's much you can do.

Comment: The `body` will always render before the `script` is evaluated.

Comment: @maX Can you add a `stylesheet`?